# After performing a batch of queries in Google BigQuery, how can I change the name of the resulting jobs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

So, here's what i'm dealing with: I need to perform about 17 queries every morning and sometimes, their order differ. So it's easy to get confused. After performing the queries, the result is the following (sorry if it is not in english):

[image: a batch of queries]

My question here is: is there any way I can change the name of the job for something more specific? Like for example, instead of **11:35[4:1]**, I need the name of the first job to be **Yesterday's Revenue**.

Is it possible? If so, how can I change it?

Thank you for your help folks!

Comment: are they run as a script? you can use [X:Y] to identify which statement out of script is behind respective line. X defines the line in whole script and Y defines starting position of statement in the script. Rather then this - there is no way to change this in UI. you can submit feature request to BigQuery Team to somehow make it friendlier

Comment: Hey Mikhail! No, i'm not running it as a script. I just paste all the queries there and use a semicolon to separate them. So, if I use a scrip it means I can change the job's name?

Comment: what you do is exactly what is called script :o)

Comment: Haha well, sorry about that, I didn't know this could be considered a script. I thought it was just basic SQL. Thanks!

Comment: sure. we can call it just basic simple script :o) Anyway  -from what I do know  - you cannot do anything by your own to make such renaming. You can submit feature request to BigQuery Team or use other EDI/Tools which support such renaming (in case if they exist)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @MikhailBerlyant, what you are doing is running multiple statements (SQL queries) in one request, which for BigQuery is [scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting). Thus renaming  or assigning a name for statement ran within a BigQuery script request is not possible; however, you can do a feature request for this using [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests).

As an alternative what you can do to identify your queries using the job ID, is running each query individually (an SQL query/statement per request), and manually setting a Job ID that can help you to distinguish your queries. This can be done following the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-jobs#running_jobs_using_client_libraries), where you can see how to specify the job ID or a prefix, using the client libraries or the API directly. You can also see the sample on [GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/blob/35627d145a41d57768f19d4392ef235928e00f72/samples/create_job.py), for more details on how to do it, see the [API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#jobconfigurationquery) and the [Python](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.query) reference.

Notice that for the Python client library, there are two options `job_id` & `job_id_prefix`, the latter will be ignored if a `job_id` is also given.

Next you can see a test I made using the Python sample, to set the `job_id_prefix` as `"code_sample_"`:

[image: create job sample]